# Finding the Max value in a two dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, list, max, iterable

I'm trying to find an elegant way to find the max value in a two-dimensional array.
for example for this array:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0][0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1][0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
```

I would like to extract the value '4'.
I thought of doing a max within max but I'm struggling in executing it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Max of max numbers (`map(max, numbers)` yields 1, 2, 2, 3, 4):

```
>>> numbers = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]

>>> map(max, numbers)
<map object at 0x0000018E8FA237F0>
>>> list(map(max, numbers))  # max numbers from each sublist
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

>>> max(map(max, numbers))  # max of those max-numbers
4
```

Answer (score 44):

Another way to solve this problem is by using function [numpy.amax()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] , [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0] , [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1] , [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0] , [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
>>> np.amax(arr)
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer in every way

Comment: except that it doesn't work on an input like [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]

Answer (score 12):

Not quite as short as falsetru's answer but this is probably what you had in mind:

```
>>> numbers = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
>>> max(max(x) for x in numbers)
4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> numbers = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
```

You may add `key` parameter to `max` as below to find Max value in a 2-D Array/List

```
>>> max(max(numbers, key=max))
4
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]])

print(numbers.max())

4
```

Comment: and how about to get the index of each sub-list which has max value?

Answer (score 1):

One very easy solution to get both the index of your maximum and your maximum could be :

```
numbers = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,2,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,1],[0,1,0,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,4,0]])
ind = np.argwhere(numbers == numbers.max()) # In this case you can also get the index of your max
numbers[ind[0,0],ind[0,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not as intuitive as others but here goes,

`numbers = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]`

> `maximum = -9999`

```
for i in numbers:

    maximum = max(maximum,max(i))

return maximum"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) is an elegant solution:

```py
from itertools import chain
numbers = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0], [
    0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
res = max(chain.from_iterable(numbers)) # 4
```