# how to get higest values in multidimencional array python

Tags: python

i have a multi dimensional array in python like this:

```
array[x,y]=value
```

both `x` and `y` can start from `0` and end in `300`

```
array[0,0]=100
array[1,0]=98
array[2,0]=120
array[3,0]=140
array[4,0]=124
# array[x,y]=value
array[300,299]=200
array[300,300]=170
```

how can i get the `x,y` of higest value of it?

i tryed to do a `max()` but i can only get the `value` , not `x` and `y`

Comment: are those numpy.arrays ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Max value in a two dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701961/finding-the-max-value-in-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: no its just a simple array but i can convert it toa np.

Comment: is just list of lists ?

Comment: sorry i dont know. i only know if a do `print(array[4,0])` it returns 124

Comment: @kederrac A list of lists wouldn't accept two comma-separated indices for item access.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I know, but I want to understand the OP data types, the OP may just want to point something

Comment: @JasarOrion Python's built-in list and array types don't accept two comma-separated indices.

Comment: _i have a multi dimensional array in python like this_ Please clarify what exactly the object is.

Comment: If that is not a numpy array, it could be a dictionary where the key is a tuple.  We need to know what the type of your array variable is.  Try `type(array)` to find out and post it.

Comment: its a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

you may use:

```
from numpy import unravel_index

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 13, 2, 3, 4]])

unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
```

output:

```
(1, 1)
```

this is just an example for a 2d array but this works well also with a multi dimensional array